# How to make the output values updated by click on the example of clocks

Tags: javascript

Time does not updates when I click 2nd, 3rd ... time

I wrote a very simple js code which upon clicking the button reflects the current time using the "alert". But when you click the second time the figures remain the same as at the first try.

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>What's time is it?</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>Here is the time you wanted to know:</p>
        <script src="/Users/nikita/Desktop/Web/Practice/Static time upon request/script.js"></script>
        <button onclick="btnClick ()">Click me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var today= new Date();
var day=today.getDay ();
var daylist=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednessday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
console.log("Today is: " + daylist[day]);
var hours = today.getHours();
var ampm = (hours>12)? "PM" : "AM";
var hoursAtTheScreen = (hours>12)? hours-12 : hours;
var minutes = today.getMinutes ();
var seconds = today.getSeconds ();
function btnClick () {
    innerHTML=window.alert("Now is " + hoursAtTheScreen + ampm + " " + minutes + "min" + " " + seconds + "sec");
}
```

I want that after every time I click the value is updating. I tried to use .innerHTMl but haven't succeeded. Sure, I am missing a very simple point. Could you explain to me please, what exactly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your time values are calcualted only once when the JS is first loaded. To keep it updated you have to generate them inside the function.

```
var daylist=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednessday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

function btnClick () {
    var today= new Date();
    var day=today.getDay ();
    console.log("Today is: " + daylist[day]);
    var hours = today.getHours();
    var ampm = (hours>12)? "PM" : "AM";
    var hoursAtTheScreen = (hours>12)? hours-12 : hours;
    var minutes = today.getMinutes ();
    var seconds = today.getSeconds ();

    innerHTML=window.alert("Now is " + hoursAtTheScreen + ampm + " " + minutes + "min" + " " + seconds + "sec");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnClick () {
var today= new Date();
var day=today.getDay ();
var daylist=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednessday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
console.log("Today is: " + daylist[day]);
var hours = today.getHours();
var ampm = (hours>12)? "PM" : "AM";
var hoursAtTheScreen = (hours>12)? hours-12 : hours;
var minutes = today.getMinutes ();
var seconds = today.getSeconds ();
innerHTML=window.alert("Now is " + hoursAtTheScreen + ampm + " " + minutes + "min" + " " + seconds + "sec");
}
```

This should fix your problem.